# Create / write files on Pepper QISDK

Tags: android, pepper

We want to take a picture on a Pepper Robot and save it (somehow) -> The first idea is to compress to .jpg file.
*TakePicture* action is taken from QISDK tutorial, then we create the File as given below:

```
    File file = new File("image.jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        getPicture().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 
    // getPicture() is The Bitmap we get from TakePicture Action.
        Log.i("COMPRESSED", "SUCCES");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("COMPRESSED", "FAIL");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the code throws exception **IOException Read-only file system.** That means, that the Robot environment prevents from creating/writing files, which I believe is for the safety reasons.  **But the picture in Bitmap format is not what we want.**
Is there any possible work-around or solutions to this problem?

Comment: `new File("image.jpg");` That can not work. You cannot use a file name only. You need to supply a full path.

Comment: By creating file this way it will make the file automatically in the root directory of the app. I have also used the App Context directory, that didn't work either.

Comment: Well the file was not created you complained. You had an IOException. So please elaborate.  And what do you consider to be the root directory?

Comment: The same code works perfectly on a laptop, it just won't run on a Pepper robot, that's why I wanted to know is there another way to convert Bitmaps or maybe a way I can enable superuser for my application, because I believe Pepper has set read-only rules for apps by default.

Comment: I told you already that you have to use a full path. But you do not react. You are talking about something else meanwhile. I talk about that IOException still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution**, I just made a file with

```
        file = File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg", this.getCacheDir());
```

This way it allows to make a fully writable temporary file, that can afterward be compressed, edited etc.
Using absolute path to the /temp android folder might also work, but that depends on Android version.